# Why can't I print the number in binary properly?

Tags: c, binary

I want to print a number using the program below but it never prints it correctly and i can't find the problem, can you help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int value=3;
    int mask=0x80000000;
    int byte=0;
    int bit=0;

    for(byte=0; byte<4; byte++){

        for(bit=0; bit<8; bit++){

            if(value&mask==1)
                printf("1");
            else
                printf("0");

             mask>>=1;
        }
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want to read up on the difference between the remainder (`%`) and bitwise and (`&`) operators. Also about how conditions are evaluated in C.

Comment: And It  use `unsigned` to mask (for Logical shift, not Arithmetic shift).

Comment: And you might also want to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: Learn about operator precedence. And enable full warnings in your compiler.

Comment: why do i need to use unsigned?

Comment: @pedrosantos because `0x8000000` overflows `signed int` on 32-bit machines.

Comment: 1) use `unsigned` instead of `int`.  2) `if(value&mask==1)` --> `if(value&mask)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are other problems with your code, but the main one is your `if` statement.

```
if (value & mask == 1)
```

There are two problems:

1. `==` hash higher precedence than `&`, so this is parsed as if you'd written `value & (mask == 1)`. But you want to do the masking first, then the comparison, so you have to write `(value & mask) == 1`.
2. When you do the masking, you won't usually get `1`. When the masked bit is set, you'll get a number with `1` in that bit, not the lowest bit. Instead of using `== 1`, use `!= 0` to see if the bit is set. You could also use `(value & mask) == mask`.

When you change that line to:

```
if ((value & mask) != 0)
```

it will generally work.

However, your code has implementation-defined behavior because you're doing bit operations on signed integer variables. On a 32-bit system, `0x80000000` overflows the maximum value of `int`, and doing shifts of signed numbers is implementation-defined. Change `value` and `mask` to `unsigned int` and everything should be fine.

Comment: None of the relevant problems cause *undefined behavior*. This is all *implementation-defined*.

Comment: @EOF, is not `int mask=0x80000000;` UB?  Assigning a value outside the `int` range to an `int`?

Comment: @EOF I think the overflow is UB, masking/shifting is ID.

Comment: @chux C11 draft standard n1570: *6.3 Conversions 6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers 3 Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the
result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.*

Comment: @EOF Right you are.

Comment: @EOF for our purposes in this question, I don't think the distinction between UB and ID is really significant.

Comment: @Barmar I find your last comment intellectually bankrupt. You made a claim, accept that it was wrong and correct your mistake.

Comment: @EOF Whether something is IB or UB, code that uses it is not portable or reliable. Does it really matter which clause in the standard he's violating? The distinction is really only important in some very special circumstances.

Comment: @Barmar: Practically every nontrivial C program will contain implementation defined behavior. This is perfectly acceptable and is not a defect at all, and is endorsed by the C standard as "conforming" (as opposed to the ideal "strictly conforming"). This is a sharp contrast to *undefined behavior* which is very much erroneous.

Comment: @EOF many programs contain *potentially* implementation-defined behavior, e.g. `int a = b + c;` is IB if `b` and `c` are too large. But if you know a priori that they're small, it's well defined. Contrast this with code like in this question, where you know that it's encountering an implementation-defined behavior. In this case, it's practically as non-portable as UB.

Comment: @Barmar Whether your example `int a = b + c;` is well-defined, implementation-defined or in fact *undefined* will depend not only on the values, but also principally on the *types* of `b` and `c`, which your example does not provide. Another example showing that perhaps you should start learning about the C standard yourself before lecturing others.

Comment: Detail: `int a = b + c;` is potential _undefined behavior_ not IB.  C11 3.4.3 3 "An example of undefined behavior is the behavior on integer overflow."  [Tough crowd tonight.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iwu-6GxBHN4)

Comment: @EOF I didn't provide the detail because I was just writing a short comment, and didn't feel like putting in all the declarations. I thought you would understand, but you're apparently not willing to cut me any slack.

Comment: @Barmar: You'll be given "some slack" when you stop trying to use it to wriggle out of taking responsibility for your mistakes.